# Where can I find the original conference paper that introduced Q-learning and Deep Q-Learning?

Tags: reinforcement-learning, q-learning, reference-request, deep-rl, dqn

I tried searching a lot, but I could neither find the paper that introduced Q-Learning nor the paper that introduced Deep Q Learning. If anyone knows anything about it please do tell me.

Comment: It's very strange that you didn't find the papers that introduced Q-learning and DQN. You just needed to type "Deep Q-learning paper" on Google to find it immediately as the first returned search result.

Comment: Yes, I agree it is strange. I didn't find the original Q learning or DQN paper at all. I found a few papers introducing modifications/applications to these algorithms but not the absolute original one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[This](https://link.springer.com/content/pdf/10.1007/BF00992698.pdf) is the original Q-Learning paper by Watkins, though you may need to pay for access to this.

[This](https://www.datascienceassn.org/sites/default/files/Human-level%20Control%20Through%20Deep%20Reinforcement%20Learning.pdf) is the Nature paper that introduced the DQN.